# ifstream passed by reference to constructor can't be read

Tags: c++

I don't understand why my ifstream can not be read in my class. In the main.cpp reading from the stream works fine, but when I pass the ifstream by reference to the c'tor I am not able to read from it. The program compiles fine but the 'inputfile' seems to be empty. In the console, I just see the content of my .txt once which comes from the main.cpp.

Am I doing something wrong with passing the ifstream?

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include "RAM.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

    std::ifstream input;
    input.open("\\path\\orders.txt");

    std::string line;
    while (std::getline(input, line))
    {
        std::cout << line << std::endl;
    }

    RAM machine(input);
}
```

RAM.h:

```
#pragma once
#include <fstream>

class RAM
{
    private:
        std::ifstream& inputfile;

    public:
        RAM(std::ifstream&); 
        ~RAM();
};
```

RAM.cpp:

```
#include "RAM.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

RAM::RAM(std::ifstream &in) : inputfile(in){


    std::string line;

    while (std::getline(inputfile, line))
    {
        std::cout << line << std::endl;
    }
}

RAM::~RAM() {

}
```

orders.txt:

```
ADD 5
SUB 7
HLT 99
```

Comment: Well, your `main()` obviously reads the entire contents of the input stream, before passing the completely-read input stream to the constructor. So, why exactly do you expect your constructor to read anything more, from the completely-read input stream?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The input file appears to be empty since you have *already* read all the data in `main()`. In other words, you're at the end of the file:

```
// File just opened, at position 0.

std::string line;
while (std::getline(input, line))
{
    std::cout << line << std::endl;
}

// File fully read, at end of file.

RAM machine(input);
```

If you want to re-read it, you'll need to seek back to the start before attempting to re-read in the constructor, something like:

```
inputfile.seekg(0);
```